# Delivering AsyncTask result to an other activty

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve my data from Parse.com during splash screen.

I'm making the query in the DoInBackground method and add all objects retrieved in an object vector (which is in an other class).

when moving to the MainActivty all data get loss.

Here's my code:

```
private class loadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Vector<PartyObj>>{


    @Override
    protected Vector<PartyObj> doInBackground(Void... params)  
    {  
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("partyObj");
        query.whereExists("Name");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> mNameList, ParseException e) {
                 if (e == null) {   
                       adapter.partyVector = new Vector<PartyObj>();               
                        for(int i=0; i<mNameList.size(); i++){
                            PartyObject party = new PartyObject();
                            party.setIndex(i);
                            party.setmName(mNameList.get(i).getString("Name").toString());
                            adapter.partyVector.add(party);

                 }
                         }else {
                        Log.d("mNameList", "Error: " + e.getMessage());                        
                    }

            }
        });
        return adpater.partyVector;  
    }  


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Vector<PartyObj> result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're using the AsyncTask all wrong. query.findInBackground() is as far as I can tell an asynchronous call so you're essentially wrapping one async call in another. The problem with this is that code execution continues immediately after query.findInBackground(), thus ending the doInBackground() method. Since you move to the main activity immediately when the async task is finished it may be that query.findInBackground() hasn't finished yet (thus resulting in an empty/partial list).

Are you really sure you need to wrap everything in an async call? Does either of

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("partyObj");
query.whereExists("Name");
```

take time to execute or is the bulk of the work already in the async findInBackground() call? If so, I'd say skip the AsyncTask and do the view transition in the done() method of the FindCallback.

UPDATE: I've read up on [ParseQuery](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html) and it clearly says:

> Using the callback methods is usually preferred because the network
>   operation will not block the calling thread. However, in some cases it
>   may be easier to use the find, get or count calls, which do block the
>   calling thread. For example, if your application has already spawned a
>   background task to perform work, that background task could use the
>   blocking calls and avoid the code complexity of callbacks.

And in [findInBackground()](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#findInBackground%28com.parse.FindCallback%29) it clearly states that:

> Retrieves a list of ParseObjects that satisfy this query from the
>   server in a background thread. This is preferable to using find(),
>   unless your code is already running in a background thread.

Since you are already wrapping everything in an AsyncTask you should either skip the async task completely since findInBackground( is already running in a background thread or switch to the blocking [find()](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#find%28%29) method.

Example without AsyncTask but using async findInBackground():

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("partyObj");
query.whereExists("Name");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> mNameList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {   
            adapter.partyVector = new Vector<PartyObj>();               
            for(int i=0; i<mNameList.size(); i++){
                PartyObject party = new PartyObject();
                party.setIndex(i);
                party.setmName(mNameList.get(i).getString("Name").toString());
                adapter.partyVector.add(party);
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);                    
        }
        else {
            Log.d("mNameList", "Error: " + e.getMessage());                        
        }

    }
});
```

Example with AsyncTask and blocking find()

```
private class loadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Vector<PartyObj>>{

    @Override
    protected Vector<PartyObj> doInBackground(Void... params)  
    {  
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("partyObj");
        query.whereExists("Name");
        Vector<PartyObject> v = new Vector<PartyObject();
        try {
            List<ParseObject> queryResult = query.find();
            for(ParseObject po : queryResult) {
                PartyObject party = new PartyObject();
                party.setIndex(partyVector.size());
                party.setmName(po.getString("Name").toString());
                v.add(party);
            }
        }
        catch(ParseException e) {
            Log.d("mNameList", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Vector<PartyObj> result) {
        adapter.partyVector.addAll(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, britzl, thanks for responding.
It does finish the query before going to MainActivity.
I've fixed some errors in my code and my problem now is that i dont know how to deliver the object i've got in the result of the onPostExecute method to an other Activity (my listAdapter Activity).

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see how it can finish the query before going to the main activity. I'll update my answer to explain my thoughts on this.

Comment: yeah... you were right... :)

i run the findInBackground on the OnCreate with a 10sec thread and it's all good.

2 more questions:

1. how do i deliver my vector object into my listAdapter?
2. how can i run a thread in the exact time length needed for the findInBackground method?

thanks...

Comment: check my updated answer. you really should chose on of the two solutions I present. Then your code will behave as expected and pause for as long as it takes to perform the query

Answer (score 0):

*I have implemented similar async class for getting parse server data*

```
 private class Getneworders_list extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ParseObject>> {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  neworders_hashmap;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        neworders_recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ParseObject> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Create the array
        try {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Orders");
            ParseObject obj = ParseObject.createWithoutData("ShopLocations", idd);
            query.whereEqualTo("shop", obj);
            query.whereEqualTo("orderStatus",0);
            query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.IGNORE_CACHE);
            query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
            object11 = query.find();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return object11;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ParseObject> result) {

        neworders_hashmap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        if(result != null) {

            if (result.size() > 0) {
                chec(result.size());
                m_Runnable.run();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

*use full for some one*