# RecyclerView displaying the last item in the adapter several times. Need all adapter items to show in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

So I am trying to load data from a Parse database query into a recyclerView. The query is loading all my data into my ArrayList perfectly, which I then add to my adapter.

Unfortunately, my recyclerView only displays the last addition to the adapter's data. However, if there are 15 objects in the adapter, then this last addition will be repeated 15 times on screen.

I believe the issue is that the values inside of the data ArrayList, for some reason, do not exist outside of the query, even though I declared it in the class.

Here is my MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends  ActionBarActivity implements DataAdapter.ClickListener {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
static DataAdapter adapter;

public TextView tvParseUser;
private Context context;
String currentUser;

Data current = new Data();

List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();


public static String BROADCAST_ACTION =
        "broadcast_action_packagename";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    registerReceiver(br, filter);

//testing Sree's suggestion
        adapter = new CommitmentDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data);
        Log.d("DATABEFOREADD", data.toString()); //data here is empty

    startService(new Intent(this, Broadcast_Service.class));
    tvParseUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ParseUserName);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ColumnTitle");
    query.whereEqualTo("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); 
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) { //returns actual Parse Object
            if (e == null)
            {
                for (ParseObject getData : list)
                {

                    current.1= getData.getString("1");
                    current.2= getData.getString("2");
                    current.3= getData.getString("3");
                    current.4= getData.getString("4");
                    current.5= getData.getString("5");

                    current.combined= current.1 + current.2 + current.3 + current.4;
                    //checked Log.d, query is working fine. ArrayList should have an object of all the data for use

                    data.add(current);
                    Log.d("data", data.toString());
                    Log.d("CurrentCombined", current.combined);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Sree's suggestion




                    //data correctly contains list of objects that I need

                }

                Log.d("dataInfo", String.valueOf(data));
                Log.d("Current", current.toString());
            }

            else
            {

            }

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); //set recyclerView to this adapter

        }

    });
    Log.d("ADAPTERDATA", data.toString()); //NOTE THIS RETURNS AN EMPTY ARRAY. WHY?!
}

public BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateGUI(intent);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};
```

DataAdapter code:

```
    package com.example.android.moneyspeaks;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.slf4j.helpers.Util;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    List<Data> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private ClickListener clickListener;
    long millisCountDownTime;
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Thread thread;
    Handler handler;
    Long now;
    Long later;
    Integer i = 0;
    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<Data> data) 
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_layout, parent, false); 
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view); 

        return holder;
    }

    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Data current = data.get(position);
        holder.combined.setText(current.combined);
        holder.codeTimer.setText(current.goalTimer);
        holder.submitCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "HELL YA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        if (current.classify2.equals("day(s)")) {
            millisCountDownTime = 86400000;
        } else if (current.classify2.equals("week(s)")) {
            millisCountDownTime = 604800000;
        } else if (current.classify2.equals("hour(s)")) {
            millisCountDownTime = 3600000;
        } else if (current.classify2.equals("minute(s)")) {
            millisCountDownTime = 6000;
        }
        final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                holder.codeTimer.setText(String.valueOf(i));

            }
        };
    }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView combined;
    TextView enterCode;
    TextView codeTimer;
    EditText codeInputField;
    Button submitCode;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        combined= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.combinedSentence);
        codeTimer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.codeTimer);
        submitCode = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.submitTheCode);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.submitTheCode) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Different.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);

                }

            }
        });
    }
}

public interface ClickListener {
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position);
}
}
```

Comment: Try replace 'adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data);' by 'adapter = new DataAdapter(this, data);' or 'adapter = new DataAdapter(context, data);' with 'context=this;' at declaration or inside onCreate

Comment: Just tried this-- didn't work :(

Comment: You should post DataAdapter code for more info. Moreover, put `Log.d("ADAPTERDATA", data.toString());` inside `done(...)`.

Comment: If I put Log.d("ADAPTERDATA", data.toString()); inside done (..) then it works fine. 

The whole issue is that I need data.toString() to be available outside of the done loop. Also, I posted the DataAdapter code

Comment: I think `done` is in another thread, right? So how can you make sure data is not null if outside `done`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but to confirm I did add the Log.d into 'done' and the ADAPTERDATA was filled with the data I need!

Comment: So, has your issue been fixed? If yes, I will add my comment as an answer here

Comment: No it hasn't. I need to access this ArrayList and adapter in my other methods (e.g onReceive()). Until I figure out how to do that, I'm going to keep getting nullpointerexceptions

Comment: Try find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656544/delivering-asynctask-result-to-an-other-activty). Perhaps some useful info for you

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same issue and broke my head googling..
The absolute solution is to create your `current` object of type `Data` inside the for loop in the main activity

Explanation :You are creating a single object and using the same object with the same value n times when you declare your `current` object outside the loop

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() before the adapter is initialized. Since it is only initialized on the callback, I think there might be a chance that you are calling notifyDataSetChanged() before the callback is done (I think you mentioned the broadcast happens every second). I can't be a 100% sure because I can't see the rest of your code though.

Comment: Anything else I can add to the question? Because if I place a Log.d("arrayList", data) into my query it'll show before the Log.d("ADAPTERDATA", data.toString) so isn't it happening before?

The issue is I need to be able to access data with the query results outside of the query. If I can access that filled ArrayList anywhere, I should be gold.

Comment: debug it, put a breakpoint on the callback and onReceive, and see which gets hit first. Also create a breakpoint on adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and check to see if the adapter is initialized. Another thing you can do is maybe initialize the adapter with empty data before doing the query, and on the callback add data, and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: So a concern that might shed some light on this problem is that the Log.d("ADAPTERDATA", data.toString()) outside of the done loop returns empty and I don't know why. For this reason, I think it's less about what's being called, and more that I can't access the adapter's contents outside of the loop.

Additionally, if I put Log.d("ADAPTERDATA", data.toString()) inside of the done loop, then it isn't null...

Comment: So, what is happening is that done() is not being called till you get the ParseObjects back from Parse. (You understand that the callback is not run until the data comes back from Parse, right?) Therefore, when you do the Log, the adapter data will be empty. And I think you are receiving a broadcast to update the adapter before the callback is finished (before the adapter is even instantiated). So, like I said above, you have to initialize the adapter before you do query.findInBackground(). And in the callback, just add your ParseObjects to your adapter and call notifiyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Okay so I added that in--thought it would work but didn't. Any other suggestions? Log.d("ADAPTERDATA") still shows an empty adapter. I've also edited my code above to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: So, that's what i was trying to say though... it will always be empty because of where you put Log.d("ADAPTERDATA", data.toString()); You are doing the log in the wrong place. The code will hit the log before it ever adds data to the adapter since the adding of data is happening inside done(). done() will only be called after the query FINISHES fetches data from Parse where as the log will happen right after the query STARTS fetching data. The log is written after done() but it doesn't mean it will execute after done(). Does that make sense? (I'm sorry if I am not explaining it properly)

Comment: Yeah that makes total sense-- hadn't considered it. This will help in the debugging process, but it doesn't shed any immediate light on my recyclerView issue [I edited the question for more clarity]

Comment: You don't seem to be adding the data to the adapter class. You are simply just adding it to the data object in the activity. Instead try this: Create a method in DataAdapter called addData(). addData() will take in a Data object and add it the the List<Data> inside the adapter. So, then in done() instead of data.add(current) do something like adapter.addData(current). And at the end do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Does that make sense?

Comment: Added this--still the same output though.

Answer (score 0):

So, let me get this straight. You do the following in onCreate():

1. Do some setup
2. Create adapter.
3. Kickoff a process that runs in another thread to fill data.
4. Attempt to log a message using that data almost immediately.

So, you expect that between executing the code in 3 and essentially the immediate next set of instructions for the code in 4, Android will have scheduled that process on another CPU, run to completion, marshall that data to the reference held by the UI thread, all in time so that when it executes the code for 4, there is actual data? Do you have a special phone where the UI thread runs on a core that's 100X slower?

No. There is no magic bullet for thread synchronization issues. Either you redesign your code so that access to data across threads is correctly synchronized or you use thread synchronization primitives that enforce the behavior you want.